# log4j: how to get the last inserted log message?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, log4j, spock

I wonder if there is way to retrieve the last inserted log to my log4j log file ?
Also, I need it to be run while unit-testing on Spock.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing out of the box, but you could implement or extend and Appender for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write your own appender where log messages go through:

[Get live Log4J messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549838/get-live-log4j-messages)