# Write junit test cases with use of log messages without using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, slf4j

I have a spring boot application, I want to write a junit test cases for the void method, So I just want test whether the log contains the particular messages.
Following is my business logic class:

```
public void processAdjustmentFeed(){

        ............

        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(adjustmentList)){
            log.info("ADJUSTMENT FEED SIZE TO PUBLISH: {}", adjustmentList.size());
            // SOME BUSINESS LOGIC
        } else {
            log.warn("NO ADJUSTMENT FEED FOUND TO PROCESS FROM : {}", lastSuccessfulQueriedTimeStamp);
        }
    }
```

And in my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AdjustmentSchedulerTest {
//
    @Autowired
    private AdjustmentScheduler adjustmentScheduler;

    @Autowired
    private AdjustmentRepository adjustmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AdjustmentService adjustmentService;



    @Test
    public void processAdjustmentFeed_ValidAdjustmentList() 
    {

        ....

        adjustmentScheduler.processAdjustmentFeed();

        //HERE I NEED TO CHECK FOR THE LOG MESSAGE
    }
}
```

How can I do it without using mockito, because am using H2 database ,I want to have a test with actual method. Can anyone please provide me some code samples to do it.

Comment: Why would you like to test already tested things i.e. logs? And  if your method is not testable then it sounds like your code needs refactor so that it's testable

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on testing `// SOME BUSINESS LOGIC` instead of `logger`. Testing logs makes your test tightly coupled and **you end up testing already tested logger code**. This doesn't complies with **[unit testing principles](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/unit-testing/)**.

Anyway if you really don't want to use `mockito`, you can always write your own `appender` where log messages go through.

[See this for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549838/get-live-log4j-messages)